# In Debian GNU/HURD, how to switch back to text terminal after I start X?

Tags: terminal, debian, gnu

I've been running Debian GNU/Linux for several years. Recently I gave Hurd a try by running Debian GNU/Hurd on a physical machine. It works fine, and I can get X running without problem.

The problem is, I cannot switch back to text terminals by Ctrl-Alt-F*. Before I start X, I can switch between text terminals with Alt-F*, but after X starts, I can only stay in X. I cannot switch to a text terminal using Ctrl-Alt-F* like I do in a Linux system.

I would like to know, if it is possible to switch to a text terminal, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore off-topic.

Comment: @FelixKling , is there any way I can move it to another stack exchange site?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You need 250 rep to vote to migrate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site

Comment: I see. I shall pay more attention next time. If you could please vote to move it to _superuser_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not yet.

(From the freedesktop.org wiki) The X.Org support on GNU/Hurd is quite rudimentary: **in particular, there is no support for switching back to the text console while X is running.**

http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/Hurd_Porting